# How to make a function loop through multiple dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking to create a function in Python that will move between multiple dictionaries that are within a class. There will be several dictionaries that the user will go through in order, and I want the function to be able to go through each one and select a random pair from the dictionary. The user will then submit an answer or some input, and then the function will move on to the next dictionary, again selecting a random pair.

Short of creating a separate function for each dictionary, I’m not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can pass a dictionary/dictionaries as an argument to the function, if I get you. Otherwise, please show us what you've tried and what doesn't work as expected and what the result should be.

Comment: So the class has multiple class variables that are dictionaries, correct.  And you want a function that will choose one of those dictionaries at random (would you prefer non-random).  From that selected dictionary, you want a random key/value pair to be selected.  Collect input from the user based on that key/value pair.  Then select a different dictionary from the collection in the class and keep doing the random key/value thing.  So in your class constructor add all of the dictionaries to a list of dictionaries.  Then randomly select a dictionary from that list of dictionaries.

Comment: If something was wrong with my answer, please say so so that it can be adjusted. If not, it's generally good etiquette to accept an answer (green check) when it properly answers your question.

Comment: Apologies about that. I need to re-read the SO FAQ, evidently.. Your solution worked well. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you've got a list of dictionaries in the class, something like:

```
import random
for d in dict_list:
    random_pair = random.choice(d.items())
    # Then do whatever you were going to do with that pair
    # then it goes on to the next dictionary in the list
```

If you don't already have all the dictionaries in a list, just make the list before that loop.